# typeError: str object not callable-python

Tags: python, typeerror

```
input=input("select the garment you purchased type 1 for shirt, 2 for pants, 3 for coats: ")

def color(call):
   if call==123:
      colorin=input("Enter your shirt colour, 1 for red, 2 for blue, 3 for green")
    elif call==345:
       colorin=input("Enter your pants colour 1 for black, 2 for blue, 3 for white")
    elif call==678:
       clorin=input("Enter your coat colour 1 for black, 2 for grey, 3 for skyblue")
    else:
       print("invalid")
    return colorin

def shirt(sh):
   if int(sh)==1:
      print("shirt red, cost=$5")
   elif int(sh)==2:
      print("shirt blue, cost=$6")
   elif int(sh)==3:
      print("shirt green, cost=$7")
   else:
      print("enter a valid color")
   return print("Thank you for shopping")

def pants(pa):
   if int(pa)==1:
      print("pant black, cost=$10")
   elif int(pa)==2:
      print("pant blue, cost=$11")
   elif int(pa)==3:
      print("pant white, cost=$12")
   else:
      print("enter a valid color")
   return print("Thank you shopping")

def coat(ca):
   if int(ca)==1:
      print("coat black, cost=$50")
   elif int(ca)==2:
      print("coat grey, cost=$55")
   elif int(ca)==3:
      print("coat skyblue, cost=$60")
   else:
      print("enter a valid color")
   return print("Thank you shopping")



if int(input) == 1:
   sc = color(123)
   las=shirt(sc)
else:
   pass
if int(input) == 2:
   pc=color(456)
   lap=pants(pc)
else:
   pass
if int(input) == 3:
   cc=color(678)
   lac=coat(cc)
else:
   print("enter a valid number")
```

## end of code

error:

```
      select the garment you purchased type 1 for shirt, 2 for pants, 3 for coats: 1
    Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:\users\abdul samad\documents\visual studio 2017  \rojects\PythonApplication7\PythonApplication7\PythonApplication7.py", line 50, in <module>
    sc = color("123")
    File "c:\users\abdul samad\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\PythonApplication7\PythonApplication7\PythonApplication7.py", line 5, in color
    colorin=input("Enter your shirt colour, 1 for red, 2 for blue, 3 for green")
    TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
    Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Also, fix your code indentiations

Comment: Yes, because on the first line you did `input=input(...)`. Now the variable `input` refers to whatever string was returned by the `input` function, which is now shadowed and inaccessible.

Comment: Changed the variable and it's working. Thank you.

Comment: Code is not working properly, pls can you help me fixing it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't call the name of your variable the same as the function `input`

Answer (score 0):

Looked at your code. Not quite get the purpose of your first line:

```
input=input("select the garment you purchased type 1 for shirt, 2 for pants, 3 for coats: ")
```

That could overwrite the input() function with whatever string you type in the command line. As a result, the later function call input() goes with that string, which is not a function, and not callable.